# How do I deploy a relocation pom.xml to sonatype's OSS repository

Tags: maven, sonatype

The instructions on Sonatype's site are thin, and the maven documentation about relocation poms references local filesystem based access to the repository files (and suggests moving the files).  I need to deploy a new version of my multi-module project in a new groupId, and then publish a redirect pom for that version in the old groupId.  I have the relocation poms ready - do I just swap them in for the main pom.xml files and then re-run my deploy (it deploys jar contents when I do this), or is there some other way to push these pom artifacts to oss.sonatype.org?  Anyone have any best practices with respect to this?

Comment: I would suggest to ask on the maven users list for that subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy new version of pom(s) with the old groupId(s).

The packaging should be `pom` and the artifacts have to be signed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>Example</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>7</version>
    </parent>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>BSD License</name>
            <url>http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <distributionManagement>
        <relocation>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        </relocation>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: (1) Does the `<parent>` need to be like in this example?  (2) You've now "lost" deploy information from your POM (e.g. `distributionManagement.repository.url`) so you would need to specify that manually on the `mvn` command line in order to upload to Maven Central.